# How do I configure Apache to serve Django not at the site root?

Tags: django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I would like to configure Apache with mod_wsgi to serve multiple Django projects on the same port (443, since I need SSL), but I have several projects. How do I serve them not all on the site root?

E.g.,

https://www.example.com/djangoproject1 would be the root for djangoproject1

https://www.example.com/djangoproject2 would be the root for djangoproject2

Answer (score 2):

It is as simple as:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /djangoproject1 /some/path1/django.wsgi
WSGIScriptAlias /djangoproject2 /some/path2/django.wsgi
```

Mounting at sub URL is mentioned in documentation at:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#The_WSGIScriptAlias_Directive